# (Java Multiclient server) No exception when client closes socket and server writes to client

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Server code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Socket s=null;
        ServerSocket ss2=null;
        System.out.println("Server Listening......");
        try{
            ss2 = new ServerSocket(8080);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Server error");
        }

        while(true){
            try{
                s = ss2.accept();
                ss2.setReuseAddress(true);
                System.out.println("connection Established");
                ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);
                st.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Connection Error");
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread{  

    String line; = "testing";
    PrintWriter os=null;
    Socket s=null;

    public ServerThread(Socket s){
        this.s=s;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            os=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());

        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("IO error in server thread");
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
                os.println(line);
                os.flush();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException | IOException | InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Client "+line+" Closed");
        }

        finally{    
            try{
                System.out.println("Connection Closing..");

                if(os!=null){
                    os.close();
                    System.out.println("Socket Out Closed");
                }
                if (s!=null){
                s.close();
                System.out.println("Socket Closed");
                }

                }
            catch(IOException ie){
                System.out.println("Socket Close Error");
            }
        }//end finally
    }
```

When a client connects to the server, the server starts to println. But when the client closes socket, the server still keeps println. Suppose the server will throw exception?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions. See the Javadoc.
2. You will never get an exception on the first write to a connection that has been closed by the peer, for buffering reasons. You will eventually get a 'connection reset'. But never on the first write.
3. Calling `setReuseAddress()` after the `ServerSocket` has been bound is completely pointless, as is calling it inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks. I found that when I use ObjectOutputStream in java server, it throws exception when the client is disconnected, which is what I want. But, using StreamReader in C# can't receive. What do you suggest me to use?
P.S. I am writing a Client(C#)-Server(java) program.

Comment: Only the `PrintXXX` classes swallow exceptions. What you should use depends on what you're trying to send. Have a look at `DataOutputStream.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `ss2.close()` and `s.close()` when you finish the while

```
while(true){
    try{
    s = ss2.accept();
    ss2.setReuseAddress(true);
    System.out.println("connection Established");
    ServerThread st=new ServerThread(s);
    st.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection Error");
     }
 }
 ss2.close();
 s.close();
```

Comment: `s.close()` will only close the most recently accepted socket, which should happen in the `ServerThread`, not here, so as to close them all. None of this answers the question.